# Random Forest classifier severly overfits

Tags: python, random-forest

I have 4 variables as an input to random forest. viz. ['superType1', 'superType2', 'superType3', 'superTypeProbability']. Where first 3 columns are Wikidata item ids and last one is probability column. I am using GridSearchCV for best parameter selection. However, inspite using all possible options, this model overfits badly. Feature  'superTypeProbability' overfits here. However, I want to use this feature, since that's only parameter that can improve the performance of RF in my case.

```
roc_auc_score_train:0.994399847095
roc_auc_score_validation:0.402392359246
```

Only using 'superTypeProbability' feature with logistic regression gives ROC as below:

```
roc_auc_score for only superTypeProbability feature:0.762852724493
roc_auc_score for only superTypeProbability feature:0.691760825723
```

Using only first 3 features, RF gives ROC of:

```
roc_auc_score_train:0.974928760078
roc_auc_score_validation:0.790185294454
```

My RF code is as below:

```
def train_model(self):
        logger.info("Using random forest classifier......")
        train = self.feature_preprocessing(self.train)
        X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=train, columns=['superType1', 'superType2', 'superType3'])
        logger.info("Using features: %s", X_train.columns)
        y_train = train['ROLLBACK_REVERTED']

        rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, max_features=None, n_estimators=1000, oob_score=True,
                                     random_state=50, min_samples_leaf=1, max_depth=9)

        param_grid = {
            'n_estimators': [500, 600, 700, 800],
            'max_depth': [8, 9, 10, 11],
            'min_samples_leaf': [1],
        }

        search = sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, scoring='roc_auc', cv=3)
        search.fit(X_train, y_train)

        logger.info("All Scores: %s", search.grid_scores_)
        logger.info("Best Score: %s", search.best_score_)
        logger.info("Best Params: %s", search.best_params_)

        predictedProbVal = search.predict_proba(X_train)
        roc_auc_score_train = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train, predictedProbVal[:, 1])
        logger.info("roc_auc_score_train:%s", roc_auc_score_train)

        validationProb = self.predict_probabilities(search)
        return validationProb

    def predict_probabilities(self, rfModel):
        validation = self.feature_preprocessing(self.validation)
        X_val = pd.DataFrame(data=validation, columns=['superType1', 'superType2', 'superType3', 'superTypeProbability'])
        y_val = validation['ROLLBACK_REVERTED']

        # Predict the result for test data
        predictedProbVal = rfModel.predict_proba(X_val)
        validation['vandalismScore'] = pd.DataFrame(predictedProbVal[:, 1])
        roc_auc_score_val = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_val, predictedProbVal[:, 1])
        logger.info("roc_auc_score_validation:%s", roc_auc_score_val)
        return validation
```

Comment: You are aware that you are using a thousand decision trees for a few features, yes? How would you expect that not to overfit?

Comment: I tried from 50, and it was working well with 1000. I just tried with 50 and 100 and following are results
roc_auc_score_train:0.99316618015
roc_auc_score_validation:0.386707500727

Comment: I don't know much about your data so I am boldly assuming the first three features are categorical and there are not many categories for each. Then I tend to doubt whether you really need max_depth to be that many. Also, you can try to increase the min_samples_leaf so that it requires more samples to enable each split, which decreases the chance of overfitting tiny ranges of the fourth features.

Comment: Yeah, define an aux data set (20%) usually where you grid search the RF parameters and try to minimize the difference between the test (20%) and train (60%) accuracy, for 3/4 features 50, 100 with depth 9 are also too much in my opinion, that's an average of 50 trees with 9 if statements each, in my opinion it could easily overfit, could you try from 2 to 20 trees and report how it goes? also, did you try other models?

Comment: @YoHsiao I tried depth: [3, 4, 6], and min_sample_leaf: [15, 20, 30] with n-estimators as [50, 100, 200]. results are: {'max_depth': 3, 'min_samples_leaf': 30, 'n_estimators': 200}
roc_auc_score_train:0.953699263275
roc_auc_score_validation:0.477439255299

Comment: @VeltzerDoron I tried 'n_estimators': [5, 10, 15, 20],
'max_depth': [2, 3, 4, 6],
'min_samples_leaf': [30, 40, 50],
Best Params:  {'n_estimators': 5, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_samples_leaf': 30}
roc_auc_score_train:0.95137440923
roc_auc_score_validation:0.491039110868

Comment: No. I only tried Random Forest, since it generally gave us good results so far when tried using with different features. In fact, it was working fine with ROC=0.82 with same features. However, to improve results, I have added some other feature in Logistic regression from which I am getting this superTypeProbability feature. The superTypeProbability feature result has improved little bit, but when combined with other features in RF, it failed.

Comment: Strange, are you shuffling the data before modelling?

Comment: No I am not shuffling it.

Comment: Try this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

Comment: I did not get that much. But is it suggesting me to split my compete dataset into train and test/ validation using this StratifiedShuffleSplit? I cannot do that since I already have fixed train and validation dataset.

Comment: Okay. I think I need to pass train_data and labels as input. But after getting n_aplits, how do I use it for GridSearchCV? Or shall I use parameterGrid and pass each split with different parameter combination?

Comment: I guess I need some clarification: with all four features, you get `roc_auc_score_validation:0.40` (now `0.49`) and with only the first three, you get `roc_auc_score_validation:0.79`. Is this correct? If this is the case, the 4th feature is pretty detrimental, although I suspect if it is due to a hidden reason. But if it IS detrimental as you have shown, why do you want to keep using the 4th feature?

Comment: just use n = 1 or do the split yourself, any news?

Comment: @YoHsiao That's the last option to remove this feature. I am debugging this feature to check why it is not giving good results.

Comment: @VeltzerDoron I did not understand what to do exactly, and how it will help me to resolve overfitting

Comment: I resolved the issue by making some changes in 'superTypeProbability' feature. Now ROC=0.82

Comment: Basically randomization is supposed to check the intrinsic assumption that the data order is arbitrary. It probably is unless you sampled it in a very unhealthy manner such as sampling the train data. Waited two days and sampled the test data.

Comment: It also checks how stable the over fitting gap is

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in `superTypeProbability`. I resolved it by making some changes in `superTypeProbability` feature. Now ROC=0.82. Before computing `superTypeProbability`, I was computing `typeProbability` feature. When using `typeProbability`  with random forest, ROC was=0.74. I wanted to improve this result. There are couple of `NaN` values for this feature, say 500 are `NaN` out of 1000. To reduce this number, I have derived new feature `superTypeProbability`. If both `typeProbability`  and `superTypeProbability` are present then higher value is assigned to `superTypeProbability`. With this, superTypeProbability have less `NaN` values say 300 out of 1000. Now, to fill up this `NaN` values I was substituting **average superTypeProbability** value which was **smaller** than **average typeProbability** value. This was causing the issue. So I am now using 
**average typeProbability** to fill `NaN`

```
features['superTypeProbability'] = features['superTypeProbability'].fillna(features['typeProbability'][features.typeProbability!='None'].mean())
```

Comment: What was the change? Could you share the experience and give us some examples that cause the issue?

Comment: I have added the details in my comment.